# How to extract an English word's root and affixes?

Tags: algorithm, nlp

I'm a Chinese student and I'm learning English words using a flashcard software. I think highlighting a word's root and affixes will be very useful to remember that word. So I'm looking for  an algorithm or a look-up table which could extract the roots and affixes.

For example:

```
foo("agriculture") -> ["agri", "cult", "ure"]
foo("anniversary") -> ["ann", "vers", "ary"]
```

Comment: It's not that simple, but you can use [Stemming agorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) to partially achieve that.

Comment: @amit I have tried that before : `agriculture -> agricultur`, `anniversary -> anniversari`. It's more like a noise reduction algorithm rather than splitting a word into different parts.

Comment: Lexicalized words of Greek or Latin origin are not the product of English morphology, and are usually listed in English dictionaries only in the form they have been loaned into English.  For the example words you listed, you should probably be looking at an etymological dictionary. ("Annum" Latin *year* + *versus*; "ager" Latin *field* + "cultura" Latin *cultivation*; etc).

Comment: For more fun and adventure, see if the etymology for [*smörgåsbord*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=smorgasbord) makes any sense at all to you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform morphological analysis. That is, to split the input text into morphemes.

I found this tool you can try online: http://nlpdotnet.com/services/Morphparser.aspx

Also, you might want to check ACL wiki (http://aclweb.org/aclwiki/index.php?title=Morphology_software_for_English), there is a bunch of tools you might be interested in.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! The online parser's result when parsing the default word "international" is exactly what I want. But it doesn't work when parsing "agriculture" and "anniversary".

Comment: I can't find a library provides similar function. Could you give me some further suggestions?